# Cronjob scheduling

Tags: cron

```
some string * 15 * * *  /etc/script.sh
```

If i declared a job in crontab by placing some string in the beginning after job schedule timings will it scheduled and run the job ?

Comment: Why would you try this? The cron manpage is pretty explicit about the syntax .. 

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't still run the job.

In fact, `crontab` won't even allow you to save such a malformed job specification - you will see an error message such as

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.w2nmKs/crontab":28: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```